# NuxtLink redirecting to wrong url

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a static generated Nuxt site. When I host it loaclly everything works fine but when I load it in GitHub Pages, `NuxtLink`s `href`s are not correct.

For example one of my link is:

```html
<NuxtLink to="/iot">IoT</NuxtLink>
```

On localhost my site index is located in http://localhost:3000 and I correctly land on http://localhost:3000/iot.

On  (since it's in a Repo)  my site index is located in https://lorenzofiamingo.com/prisma/ and I land on in https://lorenzofiamingo.com/iot instead of in https://lorenzofiamingo.com/prisma/iot.

How can I amend this behavior (correcting the root)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure [`router.base`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#base) to set the base URL:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  router: {
    base: '/prisma/'
  }
}
```